# Is there a more efficient way to parse XML to a database with python?

Tags: python, sql-server, xml

I am using the ElementTree and pyodbc libraries to parse a rather large (400MB) XML file with python. Currently the code works and the correct information is sent to the correct SQL Server tables. The problem is that it's very slow. I expect parsing of any file this size to be relatively slow, but its about 100,000 rows an hour.

Do I a.) need to suck up the runtime and make use of strong dedicated VMs to process the file. or b.) need to make the code more efficient

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pyodbc
import time

source_file_artist = 'discogs_20120101_artists.xml'


conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=my server;'
                      'Database=DiscogsDatabase;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

def main():
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    with open(source_file_artist, 'r') as sf:
        xml_iter = ET.iterparse(source_file_artist, events=('start', 'end'))
        nameCheck = 0
        key = ''
        for event, elem in xml_iter:
            if event =='start':
                if elem.tag =='namevariations':
                    nameCheck = 2
                elif elem.tag == 'aliases':
                    nameCheck = 3 
                elif elem.tag =='members':
                    nameCheck = 4

            elif event == 'end':
                if elem.tag == 'id':
                    elemtext = '%s' % elem.text
                    #print(elemtext)
                    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO [DiscogsDatabase].[dbo].[ARTIST](ArtistID) VALUES(?)', int(elemtext))
                    cursor.commit()
                    key = elemtext
                    nameCheck = 1

                elif elem.tag == 'name':
                    if nameCheck == 1:      
                        elemtext = '%s' % elem.text
                        #print(elemtext)
                        cursor.execute('UPDATE [DiscogsDatabase].[dbo].[ARTIST] SET ArtistName = ? WHERE ArtistID = ?', elemtext, key)
                        cursor.commit()
                        nameCheck = 0

                    elif nameCheck == 2:
                        elemtext =  '%s' % elem.text
                        #print(elemtext)
                        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO [DiscogsDatabase].[dbo].[NAMEVARIATION](ArtistID, VariationName) VALUES(?, ?)', key, elemtext)
                    
                    elif nameCheck == 3:
                        elemtext = '%s' % elem.text
                        #print(elemtext)
                        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO [DiscogsDatabase].[dbo].[ALIAS](ArtistID, AliasName) VALUES(?, ?)', key, elem.text)
                        cursor.commit()

                    elif nameCheck == 4:
                        elemtext = '%s' % elem.text
                        #print(elemtext)
                        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO [DiscogsDatabase].[dbo].[MEMBERS](ArtistID, MemberName) VALUES(?, ?)', key, elemtext)
                        cursor.commit()

                elif elem.tag == 'realname':
                    elemtext = '%s' % elem.text
                    #print(elemtext)
                    cursor.execute('UPDATE [DiscogsDatabase].[dbo].[ARTIST] SET ArtistRealName = ? WHERE ArtistID = ?', elemtext, key)
                    cursor.commit()
                
                elif elem.tag == 'profile':
                    elemtext = '%s' % elem.text
                    #print(elemtext)
                    cursor.execute('UPDATE [DiscogsDatabase].[dbo].[ARTIST] SET Profile = ? WHERE ArtistID = ?', elemtext.strip(), key)
                    cursor.commit()
                elif elem.tag == 'artists':
                    elem.clear()
        conn.close()
main()
```

Comment: You could possibly send the whole XML to the database and parse it there, SQL Server has quite a lot of XQuery functions

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* XML parsing solutions available in Python, beyond the one you now use.  They can be generally categorized into "`libxml2` based solutions," which rely on converting the XML into a data-structure, and "`SAX` based solutions," which troll through the (arbitrarily large ...) XML structure and call your subroutines at strategic points.